# Visual Studio 2017 Python debugger problem

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have just installed Visual Studio 2017 with the python package. I'm creating a program using the empty python module. It allows me to debug the program but after a while it does not let me debug all of a sudden and that happens even after changing nothing! There is no error message that comes up to say why it cannot be run.

It's very frustrating. Has anyone else had this problem and is there a fix?

This is really annoying, i have to close visual studio and open it back up to get it working again

Comment: How is it not letting you debug? If there's an error message, what is it?

Comment: I hit run and nothing happens, just a flicker on the screen. There is no error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be a problem with a visual studio driver. Had to reboot PC once it had been fixed after troubleshooting